# Swagger Doc not working after adding ssl to domain

Tags: spring-boot, swagger

I had swagger docs working fine in my spring boot app. However it suddenly stopped working after I added `https` to my domain. All endpoints kept returning `TypeError: Failed To Fetch`

below is my swagger config

```
public class SwaggerConfig {

@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any()).paths(PathSelectors.any()).build()
            .apiInfo(apiInfo()).securitySchemes(Lists.newArrayList(apiKey()))
            .securityContexts(Arrays.asList(securityContext()));
}

private ApiKey apiKey() {
    return new ApiKey("Bearer", "Authorization", "header");
}

private SecurityContext securityContext() {
    return SecurityContext.builder().securityReferences(defaultAuth())
            .forPaths(PathSelectors.any()).build();
}

private List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
    AuthorizationScope authorizationScope = new AuthorizationScope("global",
            "accessEverything");
    AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[1];
    authorizationScopes[0] = authorizationScope;
    return Arrays.asList(new SecurityReference("Bearer", authorizationScopes));
}
```

Spring Security Config to let swagger be accessible

```
    @Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui",
            "/swagger-resources/**", "/configuration/**", "/swagger-ui.html",
            "/swagger-resources", "/webjars/**", "/csrf", "/");
}
```

[image]

Please does anyone understand how to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not from swagger configuration. The problem was as a result of a wrong nginx configuration. In the location block I added the following after proxy_pass

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
// Added
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```